# Why "cannot use an object as a parameter to a method"?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following ViewController class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *field1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *field1;

- (IBAction) method1:(id)sender; 
@end
```

When I change the method1:(id)sender to method1:(UITextField)sender, I get the error "Cannot use an object as a parameter to a method".

I searched and found [this post](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2002-06/msg02149.html) which says "*it [using an object as a method parameter] is not a good idea in Objective-C because Objective-C does not allow statically allocated object*".

Can anyone point out where I can find a more detailed explanation for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not passing a pointer of `UITextField`.

```
method1:(UITextField)sender
```

should be

```
method1:(UITextField *)sender
```

Objective-C doesn't like it when you pass non-pointers for object types.

Comment: Interestingly, you can pass it if it is a struct rather than object